# Joining Multiple Objects

Tags: apex, force.com

I am looking to create a custom field that takes the maximum date from the Last Modified Date in Opportunity, Activity and Notes for an Account.  It doesn't sound like I would want to do a Many to Many relationship and not sure if the junction object would do this.

How would I go about creating this?

Answer (score 0):

You want to create a cross object formula field that simply takes the Text value of Last Modified Date in Opportunity then adds (appends) the Text Value from Activity after which it appends the Notes for the Account. See SF Help for formula fields. You may need to do this in 2 steps since you're involving Opportunity and Activity if you want to save the field to Accounts where you'd add Notes (assuming notes is from accounts).